# Align label to bottom of div in css?

Tags: html, css

Try to align label position bottom of div

```
<div class="row"> //row is bootstrap                                        
    <div class="imgCover">
        <img src="" style="height: 100%"> 
    </div> 
    <label>Button</label>
</div>
```

[image]

try to add display inline and vertivcal align bottow to label tag but not work

Comment: It works by add display table to class row and display table cell to label with vertical align bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

insert label button to div and use `display:flex` for flexible items be the same length you can read here , and add `align-items: end;` to set position at bottom

```css
div.row{
  width:800px;
  height:90px;
  display: flex;
}

.btn{
  width:50px;
  height:90px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">                                         
    <div class="imgCover">
        <img src="https://cdn2.downdetector.com/static/uploads/logo/Google-new_19.png" style="height: 90px;width:auto"> 
    </div> 
    <div class="btn">
      <label >Button</label>
    </div>
</div>
```